# How to Count a Group in Telerik Reporting?

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I have a report with **items**, **ingredients** and **recipes**. I am grouping by items so that I can create lists of recipes that contain that particular item. For example:

1. Item 001 Egg

   1. Recipe 1
   2. Recipe 2
   3. Recipe 3
2. Item 002 Flour

   1. Recipe 1
   2. Recipe 2

I have a subtotal under each Item group that counts the number of Recipes. I am trying to get a subtotal at the very bottom of the report to count the number of Item groups. In the example above I would expect the total to be 2, however my report outputs the total as being 5 because each recipe contains the item. How can I count just the number of groups?

Comment: Where does the data come from ? You should use code to calculate any stats about your data.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that this will help, but try RowNumber(), it is one of the functions. Adding to a textbox in the GroupFooter might give you the required output.